# SmallSearchInputBox on the search result page

Tags: 2010, development, search, branding

I have a custome master page. On this I am including the SmallSearchInputBox control at the top of the page.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl ID="DelegateControl1" runat="server" ControlId="" Version="4" />
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

This adds the search box to the page. When I perform a searach I am taken to:

http://mysite/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx?k=eaer&cs=This%20Site&u=http%3A%2F%2Faf007841

On this page the search box disapears from it's posistion at the top and goes into the main content. How do I keep the search box in the top even on this page. I do not mind having search at the top and in the main content.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm not a big fan of using the OOTB 'OSSSearchResults' page. I always create a subsite 'search' based on the search center template - which is customisable.

But be aware that the masterpage of the search center = minimal.master.
To convert your custom masterpage to a search center masterpage - take a look at [this link.](http://blog.drisgill.com/2010/09/converting-custom-sharepoint-2010.html) Afterwards, set your customSearch.master as the default masterpage on the search center.